# Solr Query, Syntax trouble with drupal apache solr module

Tags: apache, solr, drupal-7

I'm working with apache solr, and the module for drupal 7 apachesolr.
Some of our queries are very custom.

I have been looking in the solr documentation and at explanations on stackoverflow.
I have come up with the query:

```
/select?q=&start=0&rows=20&fq=bundle:(message)&fq=sm_hashtags:(hashtags)&fq=(is_uid:(1 OR 2 OR 37 OR 38 OR 50 OR 166 OR 174 OR 198 OR 431 OR 499 OR 640 OR 642) AND is_privacy:(0)) AND -is_uid:(177 OR 189) AND is_status:(1)&fq=entity_id:{* TO 2666}&fl=tus_message_object,sm_hashtags,content,ts_search,is_privacy,is_status,is_uid&sort=entity_id+desc&wt=json&wt=json
```

but this is returning NULL, i have tried a few different things like:

```
/select?q=&start=0&rows=20&fq=bundle:(message)&fq=sm_hashtags:(hashtags)&fq=((is_uid:(1+OR+2+OR+37+OR+38+OR+50+OR+166+OR+174+OR+198+OR+431+OR+499+OR+640+OR+642)+is_privacy:(0))-is_uid:(177+OR+189)+is_status:(1))&fq=entity_id:{*+TO+2666}&fl=tus_message_object,sm_hashtags,content,ts_search,is_privacy,is_status,is_uid&sort=entity_id+desc&wt=json&wt=json
```

But I am not sure this is correct.

I need a filter that allows the users with id (is_uid) and all the ones with privacy is 0 but not the users in blocked id list -is_uid and where the status is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a lot of clauses so it is very hard to determine here what could be the cause. I can give you the following hints:

**a) Debug mode**
Copy the whole query string, go to the Solr Admin console and execute that query with and additional debug=true or debugQuery=true. In the outcoming response, Solr will append an additional section where it explains how it "sees" the query you entered

**b) Investigate each fq one by one**
If there's a problem, it is for sure in the filter queries, so I suggest you to gradually try them one by one. But before of that, see the c) point.

**c) fq design**
Filter queries are great for their caching capabilities. Here, although there are some fq that I think won't be reused so much (the is_uid filter) I suggest you to split those queries in order to have bettere reusable (i.e. cached) results; something like:

```
fq=bundle:message // You already have this
fq=sm_hashtags:hashtags // You already have this
fq=is_privacy:0 // this will cache (for further reuse) all documents with no privacy
fq=is_status:1 // this will cache (for further reuse) all documents with status 1
fq=is_uid(1 OR 921 OR 9...) // Most probably these query results won't benefit so much of caching. If so, I think this query could be also part of the main query
fq=-is_uid(8 OR 99) // Most probably these query results won't benefit so much of caching. If so, I think this query could be also part of the main query
```

Answer (score 0):

You are querying nothing on no fields `q=`. Try `q=*:*`, or anything on any field. Best way to debug solr is by constructing your query manually in the solr query builder, usually http://localhost:8983/solr and seeing what it comes back with.